# How to show fish shell completions in a menu and window pressing tab

Tags: shell, autocomplete, fish

Currently fish shell (2.3.1) shows the completion list after pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>. You can navigate through the list using the arrow keys or Tab.

[image: asciicast]

If possible, how can I show the completion list in a pop menu and without pressing Tab, so that as soon as I start typing it starts showing the completion menu?

Here is a demo of what I am looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fish currently has no such capability. Feel free to open an [enhancement request](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/new) since that would be a very cool addition. Even better would be to create a pull-request since the core dev team is just a handful of people :-)